# IIS Issues - Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed. The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: iis

All of the sudden I'm getting the following error on my local web server (Win7 64bit, IIS 7.5).  I've uninstalled & reinstalled IIS locally and it didn't fix it.  IIS is set to start up automatically and I can see that the service has been successfully started.  Upon a fresh reboot if I go into IIS and click on start website I get the following error:

*"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  (Exception from HRESULT:  0x80070020"*

If I try to start debugging on my local website project I get the following error:

*"Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The underlying connection was closed.  The connection was closed unexpectedly."*

Any ideas on what I can try?  I've been doing research on the issue and Microsoft suggest making sure no other service is listening on the same ports.  I've verified that this isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check and let is know that how many sites are running on your IIS? Is there any site running on Default port 80 and on same IP? If so then you need to add the host header value to get rid out this error message.

Also refer the URL http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973094 for more information

Comment: Thanks for your help Gaurav!

I only have one site running with a virtual directory under it.  I also tried the link you provided before posting, but wasn't able to find any conflicting service on that same port.

Comment: Are you running VS 2005 or VS 2008 if so close them, also check whether IIS admin service is running or not

Comment: Your post did help!

It turns out some service i had running locally (KService.exe) was blocking IIS.  Once I stopped that service the problem was solved.  I found out that this service was the problem by using netstat to see what services are listening on the port. Instructions on how to do that are here at the link you shared:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973094

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below utility to troubleshoot the issue

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx